# Perforce — get the diff of added or/and removed files

Tags: perforce

I would like to generate a diff for the added and/or removed files.

Apparently, `p4 diff` does not support this. `p4 status` kind of does the job, but with limitation. For example, I create one file(hello.go), reconcile it, then delete it.

`p4 stuatus` gives `- submit change default to add <PATH to hello.go>`

Much appreciated for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to make my own script (which unfortunately I can't share at this time) that checked a specified change number for added or deleted files and explicitly ran `diff --new-file` against them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the folder diff tool that's in P4V? You can filter the results based on added/deleted/changed files. I.e. "Only show me files that were added" or "Only show me changed files".

Can folder diff between two changelists, or two folders, etc.